# Get rid of all the numbers and commas that are at least 2 spaces to the right of the word

Tags: html, r, replace

I'm trying to scrape this [table of regions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/Speech-Service/regions#speech-service) that support Microsoft's Speech service. I've managed to get the following character vector:

```
region <- c("southafricanorth 6", "eastasia 5", "southeastasia 1,2,3,4,5", 
"australiaeast 1,2,3,4", "centralindia 1,2,3,4,5", "japaneast 2,5", 
"japanwest", "koreacentral 2", "canadacentral 1", "northeurope 1,2,4,5", 
"westeurope 1,2,3,4,5", "francecentral", "germanywestcentral", 
"norwayeast", "switzerlandnorth 6", "switzerlandwest", "uksouth 1,2,3,4", 
"uaenorth 6", "brazilsouth 6", "centralus", "eastus 1,2,3,4,5", 
"eastus2 1,2,4,5", "northcentralus 4,6", "southcentralus 1,2,3,4,5,6", 
"westcentralus 5", "westus 2,5", "westus2 1,2,4,5", "westus3"
)
```

What is the regex that gets rid of all the numbers and commas that are at least 2 spaces to the right of the words? For ex, I just want `westus2`, instead of `westus2 1,2,4,5`.

I've tried this to no avail: `gsub("\\s{2,}\\d+.*", "", region)`

Comment: `gsub("\\s.+", "", region)` should do it?

Comment: It looks like you're just trying to remove everything after the space within each item, in which case @neilfws's should work for you. In general I'd recommend operating on each individual item in the list rather than treating the whole thing as one large string, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regions names without the superscripts are contained inside `<code>` tags in the HTML. So you could avoid the need for regexes by modifying your scraping code to something like:

```
library(rvest)

url <- "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/Speech-Service/regions"

regions <- read_html(url) %>% 
  # first table only
  html_element("table") %>% 
  html_elements("code") %>% 
  html_text()

regions

[1] "southafricanorth"   "eastasia"           "southeastasia"      "australiaeast"      
    "centralindia"       "japaneast"          "japanwest"          "koreacentral"      
[9] "canadacentral"      "northeurope"        "westeurope"         "francecentral"      
    "germanywestcentral" "norwayeast"         "switzerlandnorth"   "switzerlandwest"   
[17] "uksouth"            "uaenorth"           "brazilsouth"        "centralus"          
     "eastus"             "eastus2"            "northcentralus"     "southcentralus"    
[25] "westcentralus"      "westus"             "westus2"            "westus3"
```

Answer (score 2):

Another elegant solution is `word()` function from `stringr` package:

The first word is default:

`word(string, start = 1L, end = start, sep = fixed(" "))`

```r
library(stringr)

word(region)

 [1] "southafricanorth"   "eastasia"           "southeastasia"      "australiaeast"     
 [5] "centralindia"       "japaneast"          "japanwest"          "koreacentral"      
 [9] "canadacentral"      "northeurope"        "westeurope"         "francecentral"     
[13] "germanywestcentral" "norwayeast"         "switzerlandnorth"   "switzerlandwest"   
[17] "uksouth"            "uaenorth"           "brazilsouth"        "centralus"         
[21] "eastus"             "eastus2"            "northcentralus"     "southcentralus"    
[25] "westcentralus"      "westus"             "westus2"            "westus3"
```

Answer (score 2):

Your regex does not match because you string does not have two spaces. If you change `\\s{2,}` to `\\s` or   it should give the expected result.

```r
sub("\\s\\d+.*", "", region)
# [1] "southafricanorth"   "eastasia"           "southeastasia"     
# [4] "australiaeast"      "centralindia"       "japaneast"         
# [7] "japanwest"          "koreacentral"       "canadacentral"     
#[10] "northeurope"        "westeurope"         "francecentral"     
#[13] "germanywestcentral" "norwayeast"         "switzerlandnorth"  
#[16] "switzerlandwest"    "uksouth"            "uaenorth"          
#[19] "brazilsouth"        "centralus"          "eastus"            
#[22] "eastus2"            "northcentralus"     "southcentralus"    
#[25] "westcentralus"      "westus"             "westus2"           
#[28] "westus3"
```

In this case it looks like that it could be simplified to

```
sub(" .*", "", region)
```

or

```
sub(" .+", "", region)
```